# How to define $var only if parents('.class').attr('id') exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```
<div class="superBlock" id="blabla">
    <a class="watch"><img src="images/blabla.png"/></a> 
    </br>

    <div class="btn-group-xs" role="group">
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-info info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Information</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a type="button" class="btn btn-success watch" data-dismiss="modal">Watch</a>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$('.info').click(function() {
    var $watchID = $(this).parents('.superBlock').attr('id');
});

$('.watch').click(function() {
    if($(this).parents('.superBlock').attr('id') != "") {
        var $watchID = $(this).parents('.superBlock').attr('id');
    }
    alert($watchID);
});
```

What I'd like to do is to set the $watchID to the .superBlock's ID whether I click on the .watch button or on the .info button.

And I get `$watchID` is "undefined" when I click on the modal watch button after clicking on the info button.

And I'd like the `$watchID` to keep on being set to the .superBlock's ID if the `$(this).parents('.superBlock').attr('id')` is undefined. So the `$watchID` not to change to the undefined `$(this).parents('.superBlock').attr('id')`.

What should I do? Is this only about syntax? If so, how should I change this?

This HTML divs are repeating with different IDs, that's why I can't just set the ID to "blabla".

Comment: You're sure there isn't a much easier way to do this, like when someone clicks the `.watch` button you just find the related `.superBlock` element etc.

Comment: The second `.watch` element isn't a child of `.superBlock`, so `parents()` finds nothing. Also your JS is missing a `)`, but I guess that's just a typo otherwise you'd have console errors

Comment: How can I do that, knowing that there is one .watch button (look at the second one) which is not related to a .superBlock element ?

Comment: Yes that's just a typo, I'll edit right now.
Yes, so is it possible to apply the new var $watchID = $(this).parents('.superBlock').attr('id'); only if the parents() find something ?

Comment: I don't know how you'd do that, that's why I asked so politely, but it doesn't seem very intuitive that a user *has* to click a info button before being able to click the watch button, and then having just one watch button that isn't related to anything

Comment: When you use .parents(), you have to make sure that the element you are clicking is a child of the element that matches the selector you pass in .parents(), otherwise .parents() won't return you anything.

Comment: Anyway -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/upmwukzu/1/

Comment: Actually, you can either Watch the movie or have more information on it on the page. If you click on Information, you get a modal element in which you can also click on "Watch".

Answer (score 1):

To tell if a selector matches anything, check the length of the jQuery object.

```
var superblock = $(this).closest(".superBlock");
if (superblock.length > 0) {
    $watchID = superblock.attr('id');
}
```

Also, if you want the `$watchID` variable to persist between calls, it should be declared outside the functions. Your variable is local to each function, so it gets discarded when the function returns.

And since you just want the closest parent with that class, use `.closest()` rather than `.parents()`, which searches the entire DOM hierarchy for multiple matches.